# Jackson use getters to deserialize fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have jackson set up like this.

```
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
```

This way it only serializes fields and functions annotated with `@JsonProperty`, which is exactly what I want. However it uses `java.lang.reflect.Field.get(bean)` to get the value of the fields.

I would prefer it, if I could make Jackson use getters to access the fields values.

Is there any way, to make this possible?

**Update**

I debugged into the matter and found

```
   public void serializeAsField(Object bean, JsonGenerator gen,
            SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
        // inlined 'get()'
        final Object value = (_accessorMethod == null) ? _field.get(bean)
                : _accessorMethod.invoke(bean, (Object[]) null);
```

in `BeanPropertyWriter`. `_accessorMethod` is null btw.

**Update 2**

This is one of the Classes I want to serialize.

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class JwtAuthenticationResponse{
    private final String token;
}
```

The Getter is generated using lombok's @Data Annotation.

**Update 3**

I debugged further into and ended up with a `POJOPropertiesCollector._removeUnwantedAccessor(props)`.

It removes the previously found accessor because off it's visibility, which has been defined with `objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);`.

Since I am using lombok I can not use any of the @Json*** annotations on getters. That is why I decided to use nothing but fields, to determine the properties that will be serialized. But I always wanted to use their appropriate getters as value accessor.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure it uses `java.lang.reflect.Field.get(bean)`? AFAIK jackson uses the getter if one exists.

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs no it does not, thank you anyways. ;)

Comment: @Bohemian yes i am sure. For further information see the update to the question.

Comment: @Mr.H. `_accessorMethod` being null suggests that you don't in fact have a getter method for your field. Please show your field definition and its getter method.

Comment: @Behemian I made two more updates to the question including my fielddefinition and some debugging results.

Comment: Yes, you can use json annotations - you can either put them directly on the field, or define a getter and put the annotations on that. The project I am working on now uses lombok and fields with json annotations and it’s working great.